# dynamic Select statement

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

> > I Have the following INSERT statement(Code 1) I need to change it as it will get data from another database so need to be in form OF (Code 2)
> >     is that possible ?

```
> --CODE 2
>     INSERT INTO @V_ColumnDefinition(FieldValue)
>     EXECUTE(@V_DynamicStatment)



-- CODE 1
    INSERT INTO @V_ColumnDefinition(FieldValue)--add primary key constraint to definition table
         SELECT CHAR (10) + CASE WHEN A1.name IS NOT NULL THEN ' CONSTRAINT  ['+ A1.name+' ] ' ELSE '' END  +
         CASE WHEN A1.name IS NOT NULL AND A2.type_desc='CLUSTERED' AND A1.name=A2.name THEN 'PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED' ELSE 'PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED' END 
          +'(' + CHAR(10)+'[' + CASE WHEN A1.name=A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME THEN COLUMN_NAME END  +' ]' +')'
         FROM SYS.OBJECTS A1 LEFT JOIN  SYS.INDEXES A2 ON A1.object_id=A2.Object_id
         LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE A3 ON A1.NAME=A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME
         WHERE A1.TYPE = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID (@P_TableName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the database name before the `system view's`

```
INSERT INTO @V_ColumnDefinition
            (FieldValue)--add primary key constraint to definition table
SELECT Char (10)
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME IS NOT NULL THEN ' CONSTRAINT  [' + A1.NAME + ' ] '
           ELSE ''
         END
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME IS NOT NULL
                AND A2.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'
                AND A1.NAME = A2.NAME THEN 'PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED'
           ELSE 'PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED'
         END
       + '(' + Char(10) + '['
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME = A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME THEN COLUMN_NAME
         END
       + ' ]' + ')'
FROM   dataname.SYS.OBJECTS A1
       LEFT JOIN dataname.SYS.INDEXES A2
              ON A1.object_id = A2.Object_id
       LEFT JOIN dataname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE A3
              ON A1.NAME = A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  A1.TYPE = 'PK'
       AND parent_object_id = Object_id (@P_TableName)
```

If the database name is unknown then.

```
DECLARE @sql         VARCHAR(max)='',
        @dataname    SYSNAME = 'databasename',
        @P_TableName SYSNAME = 'tablename'

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #V_ColumnDefinition
            (FieldValue)--add primary key constraint to definition table
SELECT Char (10)
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME IS NOT NULL THEN '' CONSTRAINT  ['' + A1.NAME + '' ] ''
           ELSE ''''
         END
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME IS NOT NULL
                AND A2.type_desc = ''CLUSTERED''
                AND A1.NAME = A2.NAME THEN ''PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED''
           ELSE ''PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED''
         END
       + ''('' + Char(10) + ''[''
       + CASE
           WHEN A1.NAME = A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME THEN COLUMN_NAME
         END
       + '' ]'' + '')''
FROM   ' + Quotename(@dataname)
           + '.SYS.OBJECTS A1
       LEFT JOIN ' + Quotename(@dataname)
           + '.SYS.INDEXES A2
              ON A1.object_id = A2.Object_id
       LEFT JOIN ' + Quotename(@dataname)
           + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE A3
              ON A1.NAME = A3.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  A1.TYPE = ''PK''
       AND parent_object_id = Object_id ('''
           + @P_TableName + ''') 
'

PRINT @sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

Change variable temp table to #temp table to access inside dynamic query. If you want to use variable temp table then comment below will update my answer.

Comment: can you show me please how to use it with variable table @prdp